# Google mock with unique_ptr object giving memory leak issue

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, unique-ptr, googlemock

I am new to Google Test.
I have one base class and derived class with calling class

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual int target_method() = 0;
}

class DerivedClass : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~DerivedClass () {}
    int target_method() override;
}

class CallingClass
{
public:
    CallingClass(std::unique_ptr<DerivedClass> _drivedClass);

private:
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedClass> drivedClass;
}
```

From my Test:

```cpp
class MockDerivedClass : public DerivedClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(target_method, int());
}
TEST(TestGroup, Test1)
{
    std::unique_ptr<MockDerivedClass> mockClass(new MockDerivedClass());
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockClass, target_method()).WillRepeatedly(Return(1));
    CallingClass callingClass(std::move(mockClass));
    callingClass.callSomthing();
    
    EXPECT_EQ(_ , _);
}
```

The test is running fine and the mock method is being called as expected. At the end of test I am getting this error:

ERROR: this mock object (used in test TestGroup.Test1) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x5585d93e4770.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit. Expectations on a mock object is verified when the object is destructed. Leaking a mock means that its expectations aren't verified, which is usually a test bug. If you really intend to leak a mock, you can suppress this error using testing::Mock::AllowLeak(mock_object), or you may use a fake or stub instead of a mock.

Is there anything can be done at end of test to suppress this or to resolve this?

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]? The current code can't compile due to a few syntax errors, missing declarations, and can't link due to missing implementations of a few member functions.

Answer (score 0):

By using a `uniqe_ptr`, the owner of the mock object becomes the `CallingClass`. The leak detection expects `mockClass` to be destructed within your TEST, not possibly after that.

Note that gMock will verify the expectations on a mock object when it is destructed. See this [reference](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cheat_sheet.html#verifying-and-resetting-a-mock).

You can either avoid using a unique pointer and construct the mock object in your test and just pass its address to your `CallingClass`, or add this at the end of your test:

```cpp
EXPECT_TRUE(Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(mockClass.get()));
```

This verifies and removes the expectations on `mockClass` and returns true if and only if successful.